# ListView setOnItemClickListener Throw Exception

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am trying to access the setOnItemClick listener, and it throwing an exception. I add a try catch in there, and there login in the logcat exception. Is there something I am doing that is causing it to throw the exception?

Here is the custom Adapter:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class StudentAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Student> {
  Context context;
  int layoutResourseId;
  Student data[] = null;
    public StudentAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, Student[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.context = context;
        this.layoutResourseId = layoutResourceId;
        this.data = data;
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        StudentHolder holder = null;
        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourseId, parent, false);
            holder = new StudentHolder();
            //Associate the Items in the holder with a view in the XML file.
            holder.tvStNumber = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvStNumber);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else
        {
            holder = (StudentHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        //Setting the text for the items
        Student item =data[position];
        holder.tvStNumber.setText(item.GetStudentNumber());


        return row;
    }
  //Student Holder
    static class StudentHolder
    {
        TextView tvStNumber;
        TextView tvStDescription;

    }
}
```

Here is the listener method:

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                try{
                String listValue = ((TextView)view).getText().toString(); //This is where the exception is happening. The below text should have been commented out.
                // String text = (String) listView1.getItemAtPosition(position); // this is where the excexption is happening. 
                  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You click" +  position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  String d = "Test toast.";
                }catch(Exception e)
                {
                    Log.e("Error Message", e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" 
    >

    <ScrollView 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       >
        <LinearLayout 
           android:id="@+id/linearylayout1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
            >
            <ListView
              android:id="@+id/lvStudent"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="144dp" 
              android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
              >
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is how the row looks.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:focusable="false"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStNumber"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
        android:text="EE#" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/tvStDescription"
         android:layout_width="100sp"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
         android:layout_marginLeft="10sp"
         android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvStNumber"
         android:text="Item Description" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can you post the error log so we can see the stack trace?

Comment: plz attach the adapter used in your list because that is causing the issue

Comment: Thank you. I edited the main post with the custom adapter.

Comment: Please post your LogCat

Comment: I would except there is nothing in the logcat. It's completely empty.

Comment: How does your row layout look like?

Comment: The variable data[] is not part of the main activity that has the listener. I could not figure out how to pass the data[] to the onItemClick method.

Comment: If your logcat is empty then you're either catching it somewhere or your device isn't connected to the ADB correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely getting a `ClassCastException`.

Use this:

```
String listValue = (((TextView) ((RelativeLayout) v).getChildAt(0)).getText().toString());
```

instead of:

```
String listValue = ((TextView)view).getText().toString();
```

`View.getChildAt(int i)` returns the `View` at the position you pass in as an argument. So if you use `View.getChildAt(0)` (like I did above) you should get the text of the `TextView` with          the id `tvStNumber`.

But why are you trying to do it this way? You could have just found out the text via the adapter.

Comment: thank you Ahmad, it work for me. I am new to programming, so I've tried to make things work. Then, I can improve or make it better later. Sometimes the examples that I find that can get the work done is done the hard way.

Answer (score 0):

The view parameter in onItemClick represent the row and not the textview. You can try

```
listView1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
            try{
            String listValue = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).GetStudentNumber(); //This is where the exception is happening. The below text should have been commented out.
            // String text = (String) listView1.getItemAtPosition(position); // this is where the excexption is happening. 
              Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You click" +  position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
              String d = "Test toast.";
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                Log.e("Error Message", e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```